# Mono: non-standard public method in Object class

Tags: c#, mono, public-method

Does anybody know what is the "obj_address" public method in .Net Object class Mono implementation?

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns the address of a pinned object.

It is internal to Mono, so you really should not depend on it.   We reserve the right to remove it and shuffle it around at will.

Answer (score 0):

Kornél Pál [submitted a patch](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td1531707%7Ca1531707) that renamed it to `UnsafeAddrOfPinnedObject` which would be a lot more descriptive. I haven't dug around to see if his rename makes sense. The rename was not accepted.

Comment: Yes, but what is this method for? Is it for the Boehm GC support?
I don't see any other reason to introduce method which is not part of the standard library API.

Comment: It's not public, it's *internal* to Mono's corlib.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice it...
But, am I right about the purpose of this method?
Thanks.